# How to add interlanguages links in mediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

i have set up Wiki:Family using the tutorial #2 specified here

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wiki_family

Specifically, i am using same code, same folder, same database and different tables (they differ by prefixes) to create a multilanguage mediaWiki.

for now i have created two languages,

french and english which can be access by fr.sitename.com/wiki/ and en.sitename.com/wiki/

now i need to add interlanguage links to the article, the syntax

```
[[:fr:Main Page]]
```

does not work it just redirects me to a new page saying that i need to create the page as it does not exists while i can access it at fr.sitename.com/wiki/Main_Page

can someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably need to update your interwiki table - what does it contain now for iw_prefix='fr' ?. For example, see maintenance/wikipedia-interwiki.sql. Also I think there is a MediaWiki extension to do this, if you prefer a Web-based interface.

Comment: i am using specialinterwiki extension to add the prefix, thanks for your help